# I am tring to make Static Model.findByCredentials. But it is not working for mongoose, Express login system?

Tags: express, authentication, mongoose, routes, mongoose-schema

```
userSchema.statics.findByCredentials = async (email, password) =>{
    const user =await User.findOne({ email })

    if(!user){
        throw new Error("Unable to Login!")
    }

    const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
    if (!isMatch){
        throw new Error("Invalid to Login!!")
    }

    return user
}
const User = new mongoose.model("User",userSchema)

module.exports = User
```

In users i have set the routes properly too:

```
router.post("/users/login", async (req,res) => {
    try{
        const user = await User.findByCredentials(req.body.email, req.body.password)
        res.send(user)
    }
    catch(err){
        res.status(400).send()
    }
})
```

But i get 400 Bad request error. The route is catching the error.
findByCredentials is not working?
What is my mistake??

Comment: instead of `res.status(400).send()` in catch statement output `err` to console to see exactly what is the error you are getting

Comment: i am gettting the error, Invalid!!!
The problem is const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
    if (!isMatch){
        throw new Error("Invalid to Login!!")
    }

this part, here the passwords are not getting compared!!!